# How to find the Specific attribute value in android?

Tags: android

I'm searching for a specific value adopted in default component in android.
For example the colorPrimary is adopted to background color and the colorOnPrimary is adopted to text color in default button.
I want to know where the attrs are set to the button.
The button class is like below.

```
@RemoteView
public class Button extends TextView {

    public Button(Context context) {
        this(context, null);
    }

    public Button(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        this(context, attrs, com.android.internal.R.attr.buttonStyle);
    }

    public Button(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        this(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, 0);
    }

    public Button(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr, int defStyleRes) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes);
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getAccessibilityClassName() {
        return Button.class.getName();
    }

    @Override
    public PointerIcon onResolvePointerIcon(MotionEvent event, int pointerIndex) {
        if (getPointerIcon() == null && isClickable() && isEnabled()) {
            return PointerIcon.getSystemIcon(getContext(), PointerIcon.TYPE_HAND);
        }
        return super.onResolvePointerIcon(event, pointerIndex);
    }
}
```

So I searched R.attr.buttonStyle in android platform_frameworks_base repository, and found this codes, so searched again about this.

```
       <!-- Button styles -->
        <item name="buttonStyle">@style/Widget.Button</item> <!-- themes.xml -->

    <!-- styles.xml -->
    <style name="Widget.Button">
        <item name="background">@drawable/btn_default</item>
        <item name="focusable">true</item>
        <item name="clickable">true</item>
        <item name="textAppearance">?attr/textAppearanceSmallInverse</item>
        <item name="textColor">@color/primary_text_light</item>
        <item name="gravity">center_vertical|center_horizontal</item>
    </style>
```

*btn_default.xml*

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_window_focused="false" android:state_enabled="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/btn_default_normal" />
    <item android:state_window_focused="false" android:state_enabled="false"
        android:drawable="@drawable/btn_default_normal_disable" />
    <item android:state_pressed="true" 
        android:drawable="@drawable/btn_default_pressed" />
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:state_enabled="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/btn_default_selected" />
    <item android:state_enabled="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/btn_default_normal" />
    <item android:state_focused="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/btn_default_normal_disable_focused" />
    <item
         android:drawable="@drawable/btn_default_normal_disable" />
</selector>
```

About @drawable/btn_default_normal, it was a .9.png.
What I expected was that a background is colorPrimary, and textColor is colorOnPrimary.
But I can't find anything about this.
How can I find this?

Comment: You've found the right stuff for `android.widget.Button`, but the values that you're expecting are from the default style for `com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton`. Current project templates are mostly set up for Material Components these days, and that will automatically substitute `MaterialButton` for plain `<Button>` tags, so I'm assuming that's what you actually want. For `MaterialButton`, in [its default style](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/lib/java/com/google/android/material/button/res/values/styles.xml#L25), you can see...

Comment: ...the `@color` for `android:textColor`, and the one for `backgroundTint`, which is where the background color actually comes from. In those color resources, you'll see the attributes that you're expecting: [mtrl_btn_bg_color_selector](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/lib/java/com/google/android/material/button/res/color/mtrl_btn_bg_color_selector.xml), [mtrl_btn_text_color_selector](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/lib/java/com/google/android/material/button/res/color/mtrl_btn_text_color_selector.xml).

Comment: thanks for your answer Mike. it's closing to what I want, but I need more time to understand why the Button is set up for MaterialButton Style, thank you.

Comment: Assuming that you're using a modern default setup of an `AppCompatActivity` with a `Theme.MaterialComponents`, it uses a special `LayoutInflater` helper that automatically substitutes `MaterialButton` whenever it sees a plain `<Button>` tag in layout XML. It's not that the regular `Button` class is being set up with a particular style; it's that the `MaterialButton` class is being used instead. Follow me?

Comment: Oh thanks. I tried switching AppCompatActivity <-> Activity, and realized the style is different.